# Shopware 6: Product Slider data is null when use manual assignment

Tags: shopware

I have a issue with the product slider.

**First issue:** In administration, i added a product slider that using **dynamic product group** and a product slider that using use **manual assignment**.
I created a my resolver class that inherit from **ProductSliderCmsElementResolver** for loading data on storefront.
But on Storefront only display data from **dynamic product group , data from manual assignment is null.**

Second issue: On Storefront can’t display product’s cover (I still using Product Slider). Do I need to do anything at resolver class ?

Thank everyone.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @Alex My *Manual assignment* worked already, i don't know why.
I tested by add an element *Product Slider* from *Commerce* category (Shopware default) and add products with *Manual assignment*.
After I saved data, my custom *Product Slider* with *Manual Assignment* has displayed data.

Comment: So this is solved? You may want to post it as an answer or delete the question, if it is not clear what solved it :)

Comment: Thank Alex, i has fixed this issue by use Resolver extended from ProductSliderCmsElementResolver and my data is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed by the OP by extending their resolver from `ProductSliderCmsElementResolver`. By this the existing logic / template is used and the data is displayed.